# How to make a jquery function call after "X" seconds

Tags: jquery, function, call, settimeout

I have a jquery function and I need to call it after opening the website in an Iframe.

I am trying to open a weblink in an Iframe and after opening it I need to call the below function.
So how do I do that?

Here is my function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(function (event) {

            $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').change(function () {
                $('#various3').attr('href', $(this).val());
            });
            $("#<%=Button2.ClientID%>").click();
        });
      })
    function showStickySuccessToast() {
        $().toastmessage('showToast', {
            text: 'Finished Processing!',
            sticky: false,
            position: 'middle-center',
            type: 'success',
            closeText: '',
            close: function () {

            }
        });
    }

    </script>
```

This is my button to open the link in an IFrame:

```
<a id="various3" href="#"><asp:Button ID="Button1" 
runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="Button2_Click"/></a>
```

Actually this is the simple Page I'm having:

[image]

And this is the message
[image]

Comment: Can't you just use an onclick handler?  I mean, if the iframe loads onclick, can't you set the function to run onclick too?

Comment: Yes I can but it just flashes both of them at a time.

Comment: It looks like you are using aspx (<asp: ...>). If so, you should have tagged the question as aspx too.

Comment: No problem thanks for the info and I rectified it and got it working now.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can just use the normal setTimeout method in JavaScript.

ie...

```
setTimeout( function(){ 
    // Do something after 1 second 
  }  , 1000 );
```

In your example, you might want to use `showStickySuccessToast` directly.

Comment: First thanks for your reply and If I do this it just flashes both of them at a time though I have set the time interval to 9sec.

Comment: @Stein G. Strindhaug-The Iframe as well as the message.

Comment: @user944919 then whatever css class you use to select the element for the effect probably matches both of the elements...

Comment: And if you need a clear timeout, you should define var to setTimeout and put this code :

clearTimeout(timer);

Comment: aaha... this seems simple for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you could show the actual page, we, possibly, could help you better.

If you want to trigger the button only after the iframe is loaded, you might
want to check if it has been loaded or use the iframe.onload:

```
<iframe .... onload='buttonWhatever(); '></iframe>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function buttonWhatever() {
        $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(function (event) {
            $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').change(function () {
                $('#various3').attr('href', $(this).val());
            });
            $("#<%=Button2.ClientID%>").click();
        });

        function showStickySuccessToast() {
            $().toastmessage('showToast', {
                text: 'Finished Processing!',
                sticky: false,
                position: 'middle-center',
                type: 'success',
                closeText: '',
                close: function () { }
            });
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I have updated my question you can have a view at that what I mean!And I'm using fancybox Iframe to display the webpage.

Comment: I don't know much about interacting with frames but I'll risk: how about change the click function to $('#iframeID').child('#button').click()?

Comment: Actually I made it working by giving set time out to button instead of function as    var timer = setTimeout(function () { $("#<%=Button2.ClientID%>").click(); }, 9000); and working fine.Anyways thanks for your valuable answer I will try with your suggestions.

Comment: You answer is also the best one but I'm not using normal Iframes so this is also a good option who uses thes normal Iframe with Asp.Net.

Comment: +1 as you have tried so much for me and giving me new way to think.

Comment: in the update form i need a default value to be there and choice should be limited. the above function will execute only when we select. Can anyone  help me with it

Answer (score 0):

**try This**

```
setTimeout( function(){ 
    // call after 5 second 
  }  , 5000 );
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of how its differ from accepted answer and why this solves the problem would really helps to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes.

Comment: Also, let's not forget the fact that this is an almost 8-year-old question, is already answered, and has an accepted answer. Plus, this answer is really poor, doesn't explain anything, or contribute anything new (a duplicate), --- and well, read the first sentence, again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call something after N of seconds use the below way.

```
setTimeout( function(){ 
    alert("welcome");
    }  , 2000 );
```

and you can call a function in this way :

```
 setTimeout(showMessage, 2000 );
    
    function showMessage(){
      alert("welcome");
    }
```

If You want to call a function for each N of seconds. use this way :

```
setInterval( function(){ 
    // execute me each 2 seconds 
  }  , 2000 );
```