# Execute a function after X seconds in jquery

Tags: jquery, settimeout

Instead of triggering code on click of the element, I want this function to run automatically after 4 seconds. How can I make it possible?

```
$('a.close,form #okLogin, mask').live('click',function () {
    $('.login-popup').fadeOut(300);
    $('#mask').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` function.

Comment: Please search on Google before posting. Searching your exact question on Google gets you an answer on the first result... Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216394/how-to-make-a-jquery-function-call-after-x-seconds

Comment: your selector `mask` would select all elements that are of _type_ "mask". I guess you wanted `#mask` to get the element with the `id` of "mask".

Comment: @ChaotiCc ok, I'll make sure in future.

Comment: @Zim84 I've only one element with ID mask.

Comment: I hope so. My point was that your selector is wrong. If you only type "mask" then all elements of the *type* "mask" are matched, but not an element with the *id* "mask". But I doubt that you have elements of the *type* "mask" like `<mask>text</mask>`. Do you understand the difference?

Comment: @Zim84
Yes, I understand the difference between selectors. Bdw, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
$('.login-popup').fadeOut(300);
                $('#mask').remove();

},4000);
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using `return false` inside `setTimeout`?

Comment: @PalashMondal
Please +1 my question if you like.

Comment: @PrateekSaini bro don't know why you got down votes, its a genuine question :/

Comment: because of low search effort and the question has been answered here multiple times. First google result for the same title for example answers exactly what is asked here.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function () {
   $('.login-popup').fadeOut(300);
   $('#mask').remove();
}, 4000);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using `return false` inside `setTimeout`? Just wanted to know..

Comment: Nothing. I wasn't careful and just copied the function from question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in `setTimeout()` function in JavaScript. For executing a function after a period of time, there is no need to use jQuery:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    // your function goes here

    $('.login-popup').fadeOut(300);
    $('#mask').remove();
}, 4000); // this number is in milliseconds
```

---

References:

- [How JavaScript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) - John Resig weblog
- [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) - MDN

Comment: Isn't `$('.login-popup').fadeOut(300);` jQuery?

Comment: @PalashMondal I mean that `setTimeout` isn't jQuery. As question was: _Execute a function after X seconds in_ **jquery**.

Comment: okay, i just focused on _There is no need to use jQuery_. You can also make that clear in your answer too :)

Comment: @NOX
Thanks for your answer. Can you +1 my answer? It's a genuine question :(

Answer (score 0):

use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

```
setTimeout(function(){
       $('.login-popup').fadeOut(300);
       $('#mask').remove();
 },4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#okLogin').click();
}, 4000);
```

IMPORTANT `live()` method is deprecated. use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a.close,form #okLogin, mask').on('click', function () {
    $('.login-popup').fadeOut(300);
    $('#mask').remove();
    return false;
});

$(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#okLogin').triggerHandler('click')
    }, 4000);
});
```