# setTimeout won't execute the function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I even looked at this and this solution still didn't help me : [Execute a function after X seconds in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813672/execute-a-function-after-x-seconds-in-jquery)

Here is my code:

```
// featured bounce
$('#featured .animated').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('bounce');
    setTimeout( function(){
        $(this).removeClass('bounce');},
        1300
    );
});
```

The adding of the class works, but the  setTimeout ordeal will not work. It won't even execute and not javascript error is thrown in the Chrome console. I feel like I have everything typed out correctly.. the class on the .animated object after the addClass() looks like this:

"animated bounce"

And the animation plays, but then it NEVER removes the "bounce" from the class attribute.

Any help?

Comment: The context of "this" in your timer has no reference. You need to pass this to the timer function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of this is pointing at window, not the element you expect.

```
$('#featured .animated').hover(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.addClass('bounce');
    setTimeout( function(){
        elem.removeClass('bounce');},
        1300
    );
});
```

Comment: Yeah the site I mimicked was the creator of this animatejs script and he did it that way too : http://daneden.me/animate/
What way am I suppose to be doing it as?

Answer (score 3):

Using [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) correctly, you can avoid cheap context hacks like `var that = this`.

```
// featured bounce
$('#featured .animated').hover(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.addClass('bounce');
    setTimeout(elem.removeClass.bind(elem, 'bounce'), 1300);
});
```

Side Note: Function.prototype.bind is an ES5 addition and browser support needs to be considered. See the compatibility table at the bottom of the MDN article on the function.

Comment: +1 Very cool solution. I've deleted mine because yours is simpler.

Comment: `#sza { tact: none; }`

Comment: `naomik.laughAt.apply(naomik, sza, Itay);`

Comment: @naomik `setTimeout(function(){grab_beer(me, naomik);}, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2)`

Comment: Have you learned nothing from my post!? `setTimeout(grabBeer.bind(null, me, naomik, 7200000);` ps. I don't drink.

Comment: @naomik they are equivalent and nothing different internally.

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#featured .animated').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('bounce');
    (function(that) {
        setTimeout( function(){
            // use `that` instead of `this`
            $(that).removeClass('bounce');
        }, 1300);
     })(this); //pass `this` into this function
});
```

Comment: I did not ask any questions.

Comment: He meant your answer. Code-only answers are rarely helpful on their own.

Comment: Yikes. This is a seriously roundabout way to manage the context for the setTimeout.